# I want to perform a mathematical operation from values in a string

Tags: c++

```
string resistance;
ifstream in;
in.open(filename);
while (!in.eof())
{
    getline(in, resistance);
    cout << resistance <<endl;
}
in.close();
```

That is the code im using to read from the file.
The output from the file is:
for example:

10  25  10  60  45  35

10  45  23  45  65  88

I want to take each line and perform a mathematical operation by each each value of the line to a variable

Comment: You should be using `while (getline(...))`, but it sounds like you want a call to `std::accumulate`?

Comment: What operation are you going to perform?

Comment: Is the `in.getline` method not supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to perform a computation from a data file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748475/i-want-to-perform-a-computation-from-a-data-file)

Answer (score 0):

First, [split the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c), then convert those to numbers using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/atoi), then loop through those values are performing the operations.

Answer (score 0):

in C++11 you can use [std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function:

```
istringstream iss( resistance);
istream_iterator<string> it = iss.begin();
while( it != iss.end()) {
    int value = stoi( *it++);
    //... do something
}
```